# While/if statement causing infinite loop, correct input reads wrong

Tags: java, loops

I'm working on my final project for my java class and I'm having a slight issue with the opening. I need to make an authorization screen with username & password, and each user has a specific screen that is accessed with their combinations.

I've been focusing on the first user name/password since I know getting that one right will make the rest easier. However, while the username is read corrected when I put in the correct password it brings up the "incorrect login" loop, which then goes into an infinite loop even after imputing the correct password.

I've included the code below. I have the import java.util.Scanner already set up.

```
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);
    String userName = "";
    String userPassword = "";

    System.out.println("Enter username: ");
    userName = scnr.next();

    while (userName.equals("griffin.keyes")) {       //multiple users names
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");      //easier method?
        userPassword = scnr.next();                  //to be looked into
        if (userPassword.equals("alphabet soup")){
            System.out.println("Hello, Zookeeper!"); //broken up to increase readability
            System.out.print("As zookeeper, you have access to all");
            System.out.print(" of the animals' information and their");
            System.out.print("daily monitoring logs. This allows you to");
            System.out.print(" track their feeding habits, habitat");
            System.out.println(" conditions, and general welfare.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Login failed");     //needs to be fixed
            System.out.println("Enter password: "); //needs to repeat three times
            userPassword = scnr.next();             //issue with while statement?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `userName` never changes, how could the `while-loop` ever exit? `Scanner#next` will read only the next word, it's possible that there is still content in the buffer, consider using `nextLine` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your username will never change so the `while (userName.equals("griffin.keyes"))` is the same as `while (true))`. There are a few workarounds this, here's one:

```
int reties=3;
while (userName.equals("griffin.keyes")&&retires!=0) {       //multiple users names (keep condition like this)
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");      //easier method?--Not sure what that means
    userPassword = scnr.next();                  //to be looked into
    if (userPassword.equals("alphabet soup")){
        System.out.println("Hello, Zookeeper!"); //broken up to increase readability
        System.out.print("As zookeeper, you have access to all");
        System.out.print(" of the animals' information and their");
        System.out.print("daily monitoring logs. This allows you to");
        System.out.print(" track their feeding habits, habitat");
        System.out.println(" conditions, and general welfare.");
        break;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Login failed");     //Fixed
        System.out.println("Enter password: "); //3x Done 
        userPassword = scnr.next();             
        retries--;
    }
}
```

or you could modify your while's condition so suit it better and have the zookeeper's job details outside the while loop (it depends on how you want to approach it).

Comment: Thanks so much! I kept altering things to do with the password and never would have thought the issue was with the username. I'll make the necessary changes

Comment: Sure thing. You should also accept/ upvote answers that make sense or are helpful. This lets the community know that the question is answered. Or else, other people may keep posting on this. Also, it sort of rewards the person who answered :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your while condition is always true. The user name never changes so it keeps going through the loop. Also use scnr.nextLine() if you are trying to read a line with spaces in it, as next() only reads in one token at a time rather than the whole line you want for your multi-word passwords.

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` condition, `userName.equals("griffin.keyes")` will always be true, as the variable `userName` is not modified.

You probably need to change your while condition to something like

```
while (numOfRetries <= MAX_ALLOWED) {
   ... do the logic
   numOfRetries++; // when password fails
}
```